# Laravel list all user parents id's

Tags: php, laravel

I'm trying to get an array of all parents ids of a user using Eloquent belongs To relationship
here is the relationship

```
public function parent()
{
    return $this->belongsTo('App\User', 'user_id');
}
```

and here is the method shall get me the ids

```
public function listParents()
{
    $user = $this;
    $parents = [] ;
    while ($user->parent) {
        $user = $user->parent;
        $parents[] = $user->id;
    };
    return array_reverse($parents);
}
```

but at blade when i render

```
{{ $user->listParents() }}
```

i'm getting endless loop

Comment: try a `foreach` loop, your `while ($user->parent)` will always be true.

Comment: thanks for response , i tried while ($user->parent != null) but the same result!

Comment: What i mean is that you ask for **all** of the users parents, and continue asking them all, instead of one by one until they are all empty.

Comment: no i'm asking for all parents of one user only 

$user->listParents()

Answer (score 2):

Thanks all for answers , i found the error, at database table users, none of the parents has user_id = 0 , this is why i was getting the endless loop 
sorry about that 
here is my final method that works fine (hope it may help someone)

```
<?php

namespace App;

class User extends Model 
{


    /**
    * the parent of a user
    * @return \Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Relations\BelongsTo
    */
    public function parent()
    {
         return $this->belongsTo('App\User', 'user_id');
    }


    /**
    * list parents ids 
    * @return array
    */
    public function listParents()
    {
        $user = $this;
        $parents = collect([]) ;

        while ($user->parent) {
            $user = $user->parent;
            $parents->push($user);
        };

        return array_reverse($parents->pluck('id')->toArray());
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You're overwriting the `$user` variable in your while loop:

```
while ($user->parent) {
    $user = $user->parent; //  no bueno
    $parents[] = $user->id;
};
```

You'd be better served using a local scope to query for the parents:

```
public function scopeParents($query)
{
    return $query->where('user_id', $this->getKey());
}

$user->parents()->get();
```

Comment: Thank you for response yes i'm overwriting the $user to get the parent of the parent till the last parent with user_id = 0

i tried your code but its not working , it returns on user only and this user is not even in the parents !

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that `$user->parent` always return true even if it's empty.

You can use https://secure.php.net/manual/en/function.empty.php to check if it contains more data

Comment: thanks for response , i tried while ($user->parent != null) but the same result!

Comment: and while (!empty($user->parent)) the same endless loop !